# Cannot create folder or create document or upload document im my document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, file-upload

I cannot create any folder or document and upload document in my document library by any user, permission is Full and everything is ok , when drag and drop error change to "Save Conflict Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

- SharePoint 2016
- The problem occurs to specific library
- Edit folder and document is OK

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency issue. Is there any Workflow or Event Receiver attached to the library that get triggered during item addition/updation. The same item is being updated multiple times, hence you are getting this issue.

If yes, please make sure that both workflows dont update the same item again at the same time.

Similar posts:

[1.Save Conflict.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1a55af35-3d19-4577-a2b9-3c62e1c139a6/save-conflict-your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user-if-you-want-your?forum=projectserver2010general)

[2.Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d20cc75-e49d-4129-a8a4-4d0361ef8404/save-conflict-your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user-if-you-want-your?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)